# Drupal 7. Adding images to a node with PHP

Tags: php, image, drupal, drupal-7

Is there a way to programmatically add an array of images from a particular file path?? I want to add all the images from one folder in my drupal site and add fancybox styling to them, can this be done? I've tried looking on drupal.org with no success. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, just enable the php filter module, and put the php code to do this in the body of the node. Make sure you set the format of the body to PHP and not plain text or html.

So if the image is in your theme folder, you can grab and display display it using:

```
<img src="<?php print path_to_theme() . "/files/image.jpg"; ?>" title='some image'/>
```

You can get all files within a directory using php's [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function. This function will return an array of all files within your files directory, after which you can loop through this array and output all image files to the screen like:

```
$files = scandir("path/to/files/dir");
/*Unset the first 2 items in the array since they contain . and .. respectively */
unset($files[0]);
unset($files[1]);
foreach($files as $file)
{
    /* 
      Here we get the file extension 
      If the value of $file = "photo.jpeg"; this returns "jpeg"
    */
    $f_ext =  end(explode(‘.’, $file));   
    /*Checking if file is an image*/
    if($f_ext == 'jpg' || $f_ext == 'png' || $f_ext == 'gif'|| $f_ext == 'jpeg')
    {
         print "<img src='<?php print "path/to/files/$file"; ?>' title='some image'/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Joshua. I have gotten that far. If I have, for example, images that I have upload to my 'files' folder of my theme and I want to display all of them on one of my node pages, what is the PHP code I would use. Again, I am using Drupal 7 core. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, added this to the answer for you

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. Is there a particular way to do this as an array. I want to try it displaying ALL the images contained in the files folder. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, Joshua. Sorry I keep bugging you with this. I can't get it to work properly. I tried the above code with no success. I'll list what I did to customize the code you supplied and give you the error that is showing. 1) I changed the path/to/files to the image path that I have tested and works, in both the variable above and in the print path . 2) I wrapped the code with <?php ?>. 3) I didnt change the if statement parameter at all, do I need to? this error contnues to show: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in theme-site\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 8

Comment: Hey, of course you need to change the if statement. You need to change the statement to reflect some test whether its an image or not. Gonna edit the answer for you. And i'd really appreciate you selecting this as the ans to ur que and rating it.

Comment: Hey man, i don't mean to be disrespectful or anything. But if you can't understand the code above that i have updated, i would advise you to read a php book, preferable one that would take you from basic to intermediate. :) all the best

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. I'm going to take your advice and get more php education. I appreciate your time

Comment: Joshua. One more thing, have you tried this code on a drupal 7 site? I can't get it to work. I have followed all your directions, exactly. I placed the code in a basic page node and have the php format enabled. I still get the same error code as above. thanks, james

Comment: that error above most likely means that there is some syntax error in your PHP code. I doubt it has anything to do with the logic. And yes i have tried this code. What IDE do you use btw?

Comment: I just use notepad++. The code looks good to me, but it seems like this eval() error is what's causing the problem...which I think is a drupal 7 issue (meaning unique to drupal opposed to a normal php page).

Comment: I thought you were using an editor. n Yup, i know its not a drupal issue. Whenever i have that prob in a module like that, its usually some semi-colon or something missing in my code. Just fine-scan through the code and see if you have any errors. I would also suggest using an IDE. Netbeans Preferably, you'd love it :)

Comment: Thanks, again, Joshua-- for all your help

Comment: Hi Joshua. I'm still working on this code. I have gotten everything working except for one thing, there is an error showing. It reads 'Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference'. I have tried a work around but am unable to get it to work, I think it is due to the end() function from what I've read. I've seen some examples to try but none have been specific to scandir() so they haven't worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I finally got it. I changed the '.' in explode() to a variable thats value was '.' and it worked. Thanks again for your help